# Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager() in android studio

Tags: java, android

I created simple application in android studio. Im using NavigationDrawerFragment.. Im insert date picker coding but i got an error in getSupportFragmentManager() method

Here my full Main Activity code:

```js
package com.example.clive.mydatepickerapp;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);



        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    public void doDatePicker(View view) {
        DialogFragment myDatePickerFragment = new MyDatePickerFragment();
        myDatePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Please anyone help!!

Comment: Is that activity extended from fragment activity?

Comment: You are using this code in fragment or in activity ?

Comment: Make your MainActivity extend FragmentActivity and import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 9):

instead of `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

extend `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

and make sure that you are importing `SupportLibrary`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

in order to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. Then I replaced `getSupportFragmentManager()` with `getFragmentManager()`, and it worked!

I was using these 2 imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

And my `MainActivity` extended the `Activity` class.

Comment: Awesome bro! this is the right solution in most of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

Had these issues many times . What worked for me was :

**Simply extend the Main class with AppCompatActivity than the usual ACTIVITY**

In short :

replace **Acivity** with **AppCompatActivity**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 
public class MainActivity extends Activity

do

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity it supports fragment manager

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if you are using support fragment class i.e. you have to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: can you add your imports and your class declaration